# Running PhantomJS & node.js together on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, phantomjs

1. So l have recently been using phantomjs-node using [the 1.7 fix](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/pull/51) on my Mac with no problems.

   However when I try to run it on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine it gives me the following problems:

   phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: socket
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1

   **Edit:**
   The line causing this problem is at `shim.js` line 1684:

   ```
   evil = "function(){socket.emit('message', " + (JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(req))) + " + '\\n');}";
   ```

   which seems to be related to [this PhantomJS issue](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/issues/31).

   Any idea on how to fix this issue above would be helped.
2. So l tried using [phantom-proxy](https://github.com/sheebz/phantom-proxy) instead as it is meant to a kept-up-to-date version of phantomjs-node.

   However l am getting a different sort of problem when running on my ubuntu 12.04 machine:

   ```
   SyntaxError: Parse error
   TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'require('./webpage').create(this)')
   ~/node_modules/phantom-proxy/lib/server/webserver.js:11
   ~/node_modules/phantom-proxy/lib/server/webserver.js:164
   ~/node_modules/phantom-proxy/lib/server/webserver.js:165
   ```

   I do realise there is a parse error, but this is from copying one of the examples in the `readme.md` provided.

   Any help with this solution either would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so l fixed this using option **1**.

It required me doing a fresh node project using the

```
    express myapp
    npm install
```

etc.. then in my package.json file l attached the dependency:

```
   "phantom":"git://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node.git#phantom-1.7-fix"
   npm install
```

l then tested one of the examples provided:

```
   var phantom = require('phantom');

   phantom.create(function (ph) {
      console.log('instance created');
      ph.createPage(function (page) {
         console.log('spooled up');
         page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {
            console.log(status);
            page.release();
         });
      });
   });
```

And this all worked properly.

---

**NOTE:** l do not use a proxy on my ubuntu machine, this is why it worked, on a machine that l did have a proxy on, the example failed to execute, this makes me thing that it won't work on heroku boxes, however l will have a test today and edit this answer with the result.

---

**EDIT**

I checked this solution by deploying my app on heroku. When running my app, it failed at the point l expected:

```
    phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: socket
       phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
       phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
       phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
```

This is due to the fact that phantomjs-node cannot work behind a proxy unless you specify the proxy settings, and since l was running on heroku, l could not specify these settings.